# Eclipse Indigo for Java EE + Maven plugin = the Maven menu does not appear in import and preference

Tags: m2eclipse, eclipse-indigo

I have used Indigo Java (not Java EE) and the maven plugin is already installed. Or at least, I know I have the possibility to import a Maven Project without installing anything.

But then I wanted to use Eclipse Indigo for Java EE developers. This version does not have maven already installed. I can not import a maven project. So I decided to install the m2e plugin.

And I have tried to install it many different ways (information on theses sites):

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/WorkingWithMaven
http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.com/2011/09/working-with-maven-and-requestfactory.html
http://code.google.com/p/listwidget

I also tried to use the Eclispe market place for the installation of the plugins. The installation process does not fail. But the Maven menu in import and Windows->Preference does not appear inside Indigo Java EE?

NB: I am running Windows 7, 64 bit edition

Comment: That maybe an Eclipse perspective issue. Is there a Maven perspective after your installation?

Comment: No maven perspective. It is like a bug because no menu is appearing in Windows -> Preferencies. Neither in File -> Import (import exsiting maven project). This happen just for me ?

Comment: That means the installation didn't complete properly. Maybe the "Error log" view has more?

Comment: I have a very slow connection. The installation of maven plugin took times...like 15 min for me. I have uninstalled all plugins related to maven and I tried to install them with Eclipse marketplace. If I install maven integration for eclipse, so I do not need to install Maven Integration for Eclipse WTP isn t it ? I wanted to take the *m2e*.jar from Indigo (not JEE) and to paste them to Indigo (JEE)...but too much headhache... I follow with Indigo (not JEE). And also there is too much website talking about m2e repository with differents links (Sonatype, Jboss, eclipse)...which one is good ?

Comment: I just downloaded and installed Eclipse for Java EE (Indigo), and installed the m2e plugin via the normal installation process with the location http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases, and was able to import maven projects without error. Also my download and install only took one minute instead of 15. You have a normal high speed connection right? Maybe something got corrupted during the installation? I'd try installing a fresh copy of Indigo and try the plugin with the url listed here.

Answer (score 11):

Here's what I did in Indigo.

Go to Help>>Install New Software

Paste the below URL over there
http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/

You will see a list below. From the list expand "Collaboration" and you can see m2e - maven integration for eclipse.

select that and click next. Got one error in between but it's working now.