# No Maven menu items in Eclipse Indigo SR2 EE even after m2e + DWM install

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

I've installed Eclipse Indigo SR2 EE:

```
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Indigo Service Release 2 
Build id: 20120216-1857
```

and even after installing m2e from Marketplace I don't have any Maven menu items in File->Import, File->New->Project..., or Window->Preferences.

I'm really confused. I'm on a Fedora 17 x64 machine - and my *other* Fedora 17 x64 machine at work works fine with the same version of Eclipse!

m2e is clearly shown in "Installed Software":

```
  m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse   1.0.200.20111228-1245   org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group   Eclipse.org - m2e
```

... and appears in a configuration report. Yet it is completely invisible in the UI, and it's driving me insane.

**UPDATE:** There's something in the error log that might be significant - at least, it's m2e related. See `-consolelog` [here](http://pastebin.com/Ld0tpwLB) or abbreviated paste near end of post.

I'm fairly new to Eclipse so I'm probably doing something stupid - but whatever it is, Eclipse could make it more obvious what's wrong.

This isn't the same as ["Eclipse Indigo for JAVA EE + Maven plugin = the Maven menu does not appear in import and preference"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378602/eclipse-indigo-for-java-ee-maven-plugin-the-maven-menu-does-not-appear-in-im); their m2e wasn't properly installed, this shows up as installed and Eclipse won't reinstall it because it's already installed and thus greyed out in "Install new software...".

No errors are emitted on stdout/stderr when Eclipse is launched from the command line.

I'm using:

```
java -version
java version "1.7.0_b147-icedtea"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (fedora-2.1.fc17.6-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 22.0-b10, mixed mode)
```

which works fine on the workstation at work. `ls -d plugins/*m2e*` shows:

```
plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.archetype.common_1.0.200.20111228-1245           plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender_1.0.200.20111228-1245.jar
plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.core_1.0.200.20111228-1245.jar                   plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration_1.0.200.20111228-1245.jar
plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui_1.0.200.20111228-1245.jar                plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.indexer_1.0.200.20111228-1245
plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.discovery_1.0.200.20111228-1245.jar              plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.0.200.20111228-1245
plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.editor_1.0.200.20111228-1245.jar                 plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.model.edit_1.0.200.20111228-1245.jar
plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.editor.xml_1.0.200.20111228-1245.jar             plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.refactoring_1.0.200.20111228-1245.jar
plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.jdt_1.0.200.20111228-1245.jar                    plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.scm_1.0.200.20111228-1245.jar
plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.launching_1.0.200.20111228-1245.jar              plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.usagedata_1.0.200.20111228-1245.jar
plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.lifecyclemapping.defaults_1.0.200.20111228-1245  plugins/org.sonatype.m2e.mavenarchiver_0.15.0.201109290002.jar
```

The `-consolelog` error that may be significant:

```
16:58:08,042 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Could not create component [filter] of type [org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender.ConsoleAppenderFilter] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender.ConsoleAppenderFilter
        at java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender.ConsoleAppenderFilter
        at      at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:513)
        at      at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
        at      at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
        at      at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
        at      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:110)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA.begin(NestedComplexPropertyIA.java:100)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.callBeginAction(Interpreter.java:273)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.startElement(Interpreter.java:145)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.startElement(Interpreter.java:127)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.EventPlayer.play(EventPlayer.java:40)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.play(Interpreter.java:332)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:126)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:93)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:52)
        at      at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.loadConfiguration(LogPlugin.java:190)
        at      at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.configureLogback(LogPlugin.java:149)
        at      at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.access$2(LogPlugin.java:112)
        at      at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin$1.run(LogPlugin.java:65)
        at      at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
        at      at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

Installed software list from Eclipse:

```
  Context and Dependency Injection Tools    1.2.0.v20120504-0314-H63-Beta3  org.jboss.tools.cdi.feature.feature.group   JBoss by Red Hat
  Eclipse EGit  1.3.0.201202151440-r    org.eclipse.egit.feature.group  Eclipse EGit
  Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers    1.4.2.20120213-0813 epp.package.jee null
  Eclipse JGit  1.3.0.201202151440-r    org.eclipse.jgit.feature.group  Eclipse JGit
  Forge Tools   1.0.0.v20120504-2048-H71-Beta3  org.jboss.tools.forge.feature.feature.group JBoss by Red Hat
  Hibernate Tools   3.4.0.v20120504-2121-H72-Beta3  org.hibernate.eclipse.feature.feature.group JBoss by Red Hat
  JBoss Archives Tools  3.2.1.v20120504-0235-H64-Beta3  org.jboss.ide.eclipse.archives.feature.feature.group    JBoss by Red Hat
  JBoss Central Community   1.0.0.v20120514-1749-H82-Beta3  org.jboss.tools.community.central.feature.feature.group JBoss by Red Hat
  JBoss JAX-RS Tools    1.2.2.v20120514-1752-H106-Beta3 org.jboss.tools.ws.jaxrs.feature.feature.group  JBoss by Red Hat
  JBoss Maven CDI Configurator  1.3.0.v20120514-1625-H96-Beta3  org.jboss.tools.maven.cdi.feature.feature.group JBoss by Red Hat
  JBoss Maven Hibernate Configurator    1.3.0.v20120514-1625-H96-Beta3  org.jboss.tools.maven.hibernate.feature.feature.group   JBoss by Red Hat
  JBoss Maven Integration   1.3.0.v20120514-1625-H96-Beta3  org.jboss.tools.maven.feature.feature.group JBoss by Red Hat
  JBoss Maven JAX-RS Configurator   1.3.0.v20120514-1625-H96-Beta3  org.jboss.tools.maven.jaxrs.feature.feature.group   JBoss by Red Hat
  JBoss Maven JPA Configurator  1.3.0.v20120514-1625-H96-Beta3  org.jboss.tools.maven.jpa.feature.feature.group JBoss by Red Hat
  JBoss Maven JSF Configurator  1.3.0.v20120514-1625-H96-Beta3  org.jboss.tools.maven.jsf.feature.feature.group JBoss by Red Hat
  JBoss Maven Project Examples  1.3.0.v20120514-1625-H96-Beta3  org.jboss.tools.maven.project.examples.feature.feature.group    JBoss by Red Hat
  JBoss Maven Seam Integration  1.3.0.v20120514-1625-H96-Beta3  org.jboss.tools.maven.seam.feature.feature.group    JBoss by Red Hat
  JBoss OpenShift Tools 2.3.0.v20120510-2034-H93-Beta3  org.jboss.tools.openshift.express.feature.feature.group JBoss by Red Hat
  JBoss Packaging Maven Configurators   1.3.0.v20120514-1625-H96-Beta3  org.jboss.tools.maven.jbosspackaging.feature.feature.group  JBoss by Red Hat
  JBoss Runtime AS Detector 1.3.0.v20120504-1621-H89-Beta3  org.jboss.tools.runtime.as.detector.feature.feature.group   JBoss by Red Hat
  JBoss Runtime Detection Core  1.3.0.v20120504-1621-H89-Beta3  org.jboss.tools.runtime.core.feature.feature.group  JBoss by Red Hat
  JBoss Tools Community Project Examples    1.2.1.v20120504-1659-H91-Beta3  org.jboss.tools.community.project.examples.feature.feature.group    JBoss by Red Hat
  JBoss Tools EGit Integration (Experimental)   2.3.0.v20120510-2034-H93-Beta3  org.jboss.tools.openshift.egit.integration.feature.feature.group    JBoss by Red Hat
  JBoss Tools Java Standard Tools   3.3.0.v20120504-2056-H66-Beta3  org.jboss.tools.jst.feature.feature.group   null
  JBoss Tools JDT Extensions    3.3.0.v20120510-2001-H58-Beta3  org.jboss.tools.common.jdt.feature.feature.group    JBoss by Red Hat
  JBoss Tools JSF   3.3.0.v20120504-0520-H88-Beta3  org.jboss.tools.jsf.feature.feature.group   JBoss by Red Hat
  JBoss Tools RichFaces 3.3.0.v20120504-0520-H88-Beta3  org.jboss.tools.richfaces.feature.feature.group JBoss by Red Hat
  JBoss Tools Source Lookup 1.3.0.v20120514-1625-H96-Beta3  org.jboss.tools.maven.sourcelookup.feature.feature.group    JBoss by Red Hat
  JBoss Tools Usage Reporting   1.1.0.v20120504-2022-H52-Beta3  org.jboss.tools.usage.feature.feature.group JBoss by Red Hat
  JBoss Tools Visual Page Editor    3.3.0.v20120504-2124-H75-Beta3  org.jboss.tools.vpe.feature.feature.group   null
  JBoss WebServices Tools   1.2.2.v20120514-1752-H106-Beta3 org.jboss.tools.ws.feature.feature.group    JBoss by Red Hat
  JBossAS Tools 2.3.0.v20120504-2054-H105-Beta3 org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.feature.feature.group  JBoss by Red Hat
  JMX Console   1.2.0.v20120504-0232-H50-Beta3  org.jboss.tools.jmx.feature.feature.group   JBoss by Red Hat
  m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse   1.0.200.20111228-1245   org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group   Eclipse.org - m2e
  m2e - slf4j over logback logging (Optional)   1.0.200.20111228-1245   org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature.feature.group   Eclipse.org - m2e
  Maven Integration for WTP 0.15.2.20120306-2040    org.maven.ide.eclipse.wtp.feature.feature.group JBoss by Red Hat
  Maven Profiles Management 1.3.0.v20120514-1625-H96-Beta3  org.jboss.tools.maven.profiles.feature.feature.group    JBoss by Red Hat
  Project Examples  1.2.1.v20120504-1659-H91-Beta3  org.jboss.tools.project.examples.feature.feature.group  JBoss by Red Hat
  Seam 3 Tools  1.2.0.v20120504-0314-H63-Beta3  org.jboss.tools.cdi.seam.feature.feature.group  JBoss by Red Hat
```

Comment: Interestingly, the Jboss Developer Studio beta works fine. https://devstudio.jboss.com/earlyaccess/ . It seems to be an Eclipse with all this stuff pre-integrated, so going with that for now. Very interested in why this seems to be broken though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked around this issue by downloading and installing ["Eclipse IDE for Java Developers"](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/indigosr2)  (ie: *not* the EE package). Unlike the EE version of Eclipse, the basic Java version comes with m2e built-in, and it worked out of the box. The preferences entry was there, the import items were present in the menus, etc.

I then just installed the "Eclipse Java EE Developer tools" from "Help -> Install new software...". I don't know if it's a complete EE package, but the EE perspective and the tools I need are there. You can compare the [Eclipse EE package list](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/indigosr2) to the above list for the plain Java version, showing that the EE package has the following additional feature packages:

- org.eclipse.datatools (Data Tools)
- org.eclipse.jpt (Java Persistence Tools)
- org.eclipse.jsf (JavaServer faces)
- org.eclipse.jst (? Seems to be parts from Web Tools Platform and parts from core ?)
- org.eclipse.pde (Plugin development environment)
- org.eclipse.rse (Remote System Explorer)
- org.eclipse.tm (Target Management Terminal)
- org.eclipse.wst (XSL support, by the looks)

Comment: @TheEliteGentleman Because it's an ugly workaround; I was hoping someone knew why it wasn't behaving. I ended up with a better workaround than this anyway: Toss Eclipse out the window and get JBoss Developer Studio, which is Indigo with everything pre-integrated and working.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to install it by following the steps described at:

1. http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/download/
2. http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=//org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-127.htm

Comment: Interesting. Are you saying that the m2e provided via Marketplace is broken, but the one from the m2e update site is fine? (Just curious now, I'm using JBoss Developer Studio now where it's all pre-integrated).

Comment: I was having similar problems with Indigo JEE that supposedly comes with m2e. Installing from the above link fixed it all.