# Unable to specify maven runtime in eclipse preferences

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

I have been trying to resolve this issue for 3-4 days now but still unable to.. so please help me.

The setup requires me install following plugins,

1. maven integration for eclipse,
2. Subclipse
3. maven integration for eclipse WTP.

After that, we install the subclipse connector from  http://subclipse.tigris.org/m2eclipse/1.0
and then specify maven runtime to eclipse that appears Windows -> 
Preferences->Maven. 
Problem comes now when Maven option does not appear. So i tried to debug why it does not appear. i have given the java_home, path, m2_home, m2 and appended the same to Path. but still the problem appears.

So i tried to undo everything and redo it, but i find the maven integration for eclipse plugin that i installed from eclipse marketplace does not uninstall ,giving validation error the plugin cannot be uninstalled as other parts of the software are using it.

I googled a bit, removed all the plugin from available software sites, removed all the occurrences from the eclipse plugin and features folder. Still the maven integration for eclipse doesn't uninstall. so i deleted whole setup and start afresh. And i go to eclipse marketplace to install maven integration for eclipse and found that maven integration for eclipse is already installed, whereas installation details doesn't show any traces of maven integration for eclipse.

uninstalling it gives the error the plugin cannot be uninstalled completely because some other parts are using it. 
i have tried some of the solution given in this forum using a different link for maven integration for eclipse. but sstill the problem persists.

So if any of the members of this forum have come across this issue and resolved it, please let me know the solution.

I am using Eclipse Java EE Luna SR2 version.

Comment: What do you mean exactely with "*when Maven option does not appear*"?  You can not access to "Maven" in the "Window -> Preference" panel?

Comment: [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10830284/no-maven-menu-items-in-eclipse-indigo-sr2-ee-even-after-m2e-dwm-install                This seems to suggest the m2e eclipse link is broken. I have tried to install using [link] http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases
[link] http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/m2eclipse-wtp/  But still i do not get the maven option in windows->Preferences

Comment: Am able to resolve this issue. I used Subclipse version 1.8.x and m2eclipse also compatible with subclipse version i.e   Maven SCM handler for Subclipse 0.15.0.201210250850 org.sonatype.m2e.subclipse.feature.feature.group Sonatype, Inc. I removed the optional Mylyn element while installing subclipse. This provided me the required maven option under Preferences. Hope this helps anybody facing this issue.

Comment: Great. I think you can post this as an answer to your own question. Unfortunately there are some dysfunctions in Eclipse and m2e connector.

Answer (score 0):

Am able to resolve this issue. 
I used Eclipse Juno. 
I used 1) Subclipse version 1.8.x[link]http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.8.x and 
2) m2eclipse also compatible with subclipse version i.e Maven SCM handler for Subclipse 0.15.0.201210250850 org.sonatype.m2e.subclipse.feature.feature.group    S‌​onatype, Inc.(http://subclipse.tigris.org/m2eclipse/1.0)

I removed the optional Mylyn element while installing subclipse.

This provided me the required maven option under Preferences. Hope this helps anybody facing this issue